# selecting more than one product type for product in magento

Tags: magento

i am using two extensions in my magento site and both extensions work upon choosing product type as their type. So i am able to get feature of only one of extension. Is there any way to set product type as multiple so that i can get features of both extensions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that.
I mean everything is possible but you will have to rethink the whole architecture.
one of Magento's base rules is: one product can only have one type.

Maybe you can try to change the extensions (or at least one of them) so you can work with both product types you need.